# What kind of users I should create for one mongodb cluster?

Tags: mongodb, authentication, roles

I am running a mongodb cluster. I try to add auth. When I read [mongo doc about builtin roles](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#userAdminAnyDatabase), I am confused. In order to manage the cluster securely, how many users I should create? what kind of users should i create?

The following are my initial idea:

```
use admin
db.addUser("clusteradmin", "123", ["clusterAdmin"]) 

# for backup
use admin
db.addUser("backupadmin", "123", ["backup", "restore"])

use admin
db.addUser("allDBsadmin", "123", ["userAdminAnyDatabase","userAdminAnyDatabase", "readWriteAnyDatabase"])


############## for mydb #####################

use mydb
db.addUser("user", "123", ["readWrite"])
```

Anyone can give some suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's generally two users you always want: a user administrator who can make and modify any user and their privileges, and a cluster administrator who can do pretty much anything to administer the cluster. After that, you should think about how the database will be used, both from the point of view of administrative and of client use. You create users to fit those types following the principle of least privilege - for each distinct type, create one user having exactly the privileges necessary to complete the job. For example, if your database needs to be backed up and also have one database used by clients, create two more users- a backup user and an application user with read/write privileges on the database.

Comment: I wonder whether db.addUser("allDBsadmin", "123", ["userAdminAnyDatabase","userAdminAnyDatabase", "readWriteAnyDatabase"]) can do anything on mongodb cluster? Another question: I found that mongodb culster, replset, config servers, and mogos all have admin databases. They are different. What are the difference? what are the differences when doing authentication? Thanks

Comment: Why my user with  ["userAdminAnyDatabase","userAdminAnyDatabase", "readWriteAnyDatabase"]) can not read local.system.replset?